# Cannot convert value of type 'LibraryA.Ad?' to expected argument type 'LibraryB.Ad?'

Tags: swift

I am working on two libraries, `LibraryA` that is dependent on another `LibraryB`.
`LibraryA` handles networking and logical functions and so on...

`LibraryB` handles the UI, it contains UI components, ViewControllers for `UIKit` and Views for `SwiftUI`. It displays the data that LibraryA returns.

I am using a separate library for the UI since I want to reuse the same UI across multiple projects.
Both libraries contains the Ad model, with the same attributes:

```swift
public struct Ad: Codable {
    
    public var id                  : String?     = nil
    public var channel             : String?     = nil
    
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        
        case id                  = "id"
        case channel             = "channel"

    }
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        id                  = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self     , forKey: .id                  )
        channel             = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self     , forKey: .channel             )
        
    }
    
    init() {
        
    }
}
```

`LibraryA` can be referred to as the main library, this library handles in the logic and networking like I said. And in the completion handlers of the API Calls, I call the functions from `LibraryB`, that displays the data fetched from `LibraryA`.
I import `LibraryB` in `LibraryA`.

The following function is called in the completion handler after getting the data in `LibraryA`

```swift
// File in LibraryA

let libB = LibraryB()

private func displayAd(viewController:UIViewController,ad:Ad?){

        libB.displayView(viewController, ad: ad)
```

The following error appears:

> Cannot convert value of type 'LibraryA.Ad?' to expected argument type 'LibraryB.Ad?'

And in `LibraryB`:

```swift
// File in libraryB
func displayView(_ viewController:UIViewController, ad:Ad?){
// handle Ad
}
```

Even tho the models are similar, they still have different types `LibraryA.Ad?`, and `LibraryB.Ad?`, I tried adding extensions in the model of `LibraryA` that may help "unify" the types:

```swift
// File in libraryA

import Foundation
import LibraryB

public struct Ad: Codable {
    
    public var id                  : String?     = nil
    public var channel             : String?     = nil
    
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        
        case id                  = "id"
        case channel             = "channel"

    }
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        id                  = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self     , forKey: .id                  )
        channel             = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self     , forKey: .channel             )
        
    }
    
    init() {
        
    }
}

extension Ad{
    init(ad: LibraryB.Ad) {
        self.init()
        
        self.id = ad.id
        self.channel = ad.channel
    }
}
```

But it was a dead-end.

Comment: I'd either create a "CoreLib" with `Ad` which can be used in both Libs, or use only one `Ad` (in the "lowest" level lib, ie the one which isn't dependent of the other).

Comment: Why was the `LibraryA.Ad` init using `LibraryB.Ad` a dead end? That should be a perfectly reasonable approach, you just need to add a public member wise init to `LibraryA.Ad`.

Comment: `'Ad' is not a member type of class 'LibraryB. LibraryB'`

This is the error I am receiving when I add init() and extension, also added the 'public' access modifier to it, same error